# Set a state from useState without triggering useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

#### The problem

I want to prevent the triggering of a useEffect hook which contains a useState value in the dependency array. To make it clear, look at the example.

#### Detailed explanation

In the initialization process a form will set some values therefore I defined a flag to prevent the other effect to execute before it is fully initialized, but I also don't want to trigger the second effect when the initialization flag state is changed.

**Can I somehow prevent the tracking of this `isInitialization` state?**
I couldn't find a thread which is solves my problem. Would you maybe so kind to link the threads which are related to that? Thanks in advance.

#### Example

```
export function SomeComponent(props) {
  const [form] = useForm();
  const [settings, setSettings] = useState(props.initialSettings);
  const [isInitialization, setIsInitialization] = useState(true);

  /**
   * Updates the form settings state, just for initialization
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isInitialization) {
      form.setFieldsValue({
        ...settings,
      });
      setIsInitialization(false); // <-- This should not trigger any useEffect
    }
  }, [settings, form, isInitialization]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.settingsChanges && !isInitialization) {
      props.settingsChanges(settings, isValid && hasRequiredFields);
    }
  }, [settings, props, isInitialization]);
}
```

Comment: Remove all the effect dependencies so the effect callback runs only once when the component mounts. The official React docs are an amazing resource: [Conditionally firing an effect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect).

Comment: But `settings, form` are required for the initialization process. How do I do it exactly?

Comment: you can use variables in the effect without adding them to the dependency array. Adding them makes the effect run when the values changed.

Comment: Dependencies are used only to re-trigger an effect, they aren't used as arguments to a function or anything like that, the effect is guaranteed to run at least once.

Comment: For example when I remove `form` in the first useEffect hook, I will get those kind of message: `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'form'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.`

Comment: Just checking if I understand your problem correctly, you dont want the call to ```setInitialization``` in the first ````useEffect```` to trigger the second ````useEffect```` below right?

Comment: That is simply a linting warning, and it's *just* a warning. You can safely ignore it. If you want to stifle the warning you can add a `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` comment just above the dependency array, though if you ever update the code/logic and a dependency is necessary this disables the check and makes it easier to introduce bugs later, so use with caution.

Comment: @DrewReese Ok, this is kinda strange. Well, then I will give it a try.

Comment: Nothing strange, it's just an opinionated setting React suggests in order to avoid stale enclosures in hook callbacks. Think of it as an industry best practice. The exception being that the linter can't tell if you want to run a "componentDidMount" effect or a "componentDidUpdate" effect, since the `useEffect` hook stands in for both lifecycles.

Comment: Any chance you can just enhance your useForm hook to accept initialFieldValues? Because this approach of yours looks to me like the wrong end to fix it.

Comment: @Martin Good catch! I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Martin Thanks a lot. Great tip. Refactored my code which looks now much cleaner :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete `isInitialization` from dependency array.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isInitialization) {
      form.setFieldsValue({
        ...settings,
      });
      setIsInitialization(false); // <-- This should not trigger any useEffect
    }
  }, [settings, form]);
```

[As React docs says:](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect)

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only **once** (on mount and
> unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This
> tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props
> or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special
> case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always
> works.

**UPDATE:**

[Building Your Own Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)

> Building your own Hooks lets you extract component logic into reusable
> functions.

If it is common logic, then you can create custom hooks and share across components.

«useMyCustomHook.jsx» file:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export default function useMyCustomHook(str) {
  useEffect(() => {
      console.log(`title`, title);
  });
}
```

and then use it in component:

```
function fooFunction(props) {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');

  useMyCustomHook(`This is ${firstName}`);

  return (        
      <div>The firstname is {firstName}</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have just red this https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6880 and it seems to be a long lasting discussion about this. I don't know how to feel when I always need to paste this ignore line into many files.

Comment: @LingVu please, see my updated answer. You can create custom hook. Then share it across components.

Comment: My own solution does not solve the actual problem, but rather is solved in another way, but I wanted to avoid to pollute this question. Anyway thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @LingVu feel free to post your solution. It is really interesting to see it. Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: @DrewReese your words are very valuable for me! Thank you! Have a nice day!:)

Answer (score 1):

Special thanks to @Martin. This is solution does not actually solve the problem of skip the useEffect triggering, but helped me to refactor my code even more. Maybe this is not related, but I still wanted  to share my outcome with you:

In the end it looks similar like this. The initialization flag is not needed anymore, because the custom hook does it already:

```
const useAntForm = (initalData) => {
  const [form] = useForm();
  form.setFieldsValue({
    ...initalData,
  });

  return form;
};

export function SomeComponent({
  settingsChanges,
  initialSettings,
}: SettingsProps) {
  const form = useAntForm(initialSettings);
  const [settings, setSettings] = useState(initialSettings);
  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(false);
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: Please be aware that with the current implementation `form.setFieldsValue(...)` will be callled everytime your component renders.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html it is possible to leave out dependencies in the `useEffect` hook when they shouldn't trigger rerendering. Usually when leaving out dependencies it says

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'someDependency'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.

In order to fix this you just need to add https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks to your eslint config which is mostly located in the `package.json` file

My config now looks like:

package.json

```json
{
 ...
 "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "react-hooks"  // <-- Added this
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```